# How to identify the source that opened an aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx file, this file will be called from inside a flash. Is there anyway I could if this file is being directly accessed through the browser or being accessed by the flash?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it from the flash file, you could embed a querystring parameter into the flash file.

So, inside the flash, where it calls the resource
change from "[yourfile].aspx"
to "[yourfile].aspx?fla=1"
then read the querystring in the aspx file.

This may or may not be appropriate to your set up, but is often a quick and easy way of working out what called what in simple scenarios.

Comment: Agreed. This approach can get you a quick answer

Comment: The issue is that I don't want this file to be callable from the browser at all, so if I embedded this querystring in the flash then someone downloaded the flash and decompiled it will see querystring and can call the file from the browser passing the parameter

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy and reliable way of warranting that the caller is a flash file - I would not rely on identifying the caller as flash for any kind of security.  
It would not take a decompiler to work out what kind of headers or parameters were required to access the file, just a network monitor.   
Some TV network sites have techniques to protect their on demand viewing from being pulled by anything other than their own flash players, you may be able to find out how they do it, but mostly they don't talk about it.  
Safer to ensure the aspx page doen't output inappropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for something like this you'd use the [Referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to see where the user came from.  I'm not sure what it'll look like from within a Flash, though.  Worth testing.  Note also that it's up to the user's browser to send a Referrer in the first place.  Some don't, by default or by a user setting.

Note that this is generally the behavior of the web.  How is the Flash "calling" the "aspx file"?  If it's just telling the user's browser to request that resource, then the browser is essentially creating a whole new request.  That request, by the nature of the web, can be re-created any time the user wants.  So if you're doing everything through the browser then you're at the whim of the browser's settings.